# What is the proper way to setup your sessions in php?

Tags: php, jquery, json, html, session

I am building a web application that will host multiple users. I have a login module which takes in the users email, password and remember me. That data is passed to login.php which checks for errors and if no errors calls the login_user function. The login_user function checks to see if the user's creds are correct and if so sets the row data to each SESSION **Example:**($_SESSION['first_name'] = $row['first_name'];). Now, the problem is when I'm logged in as user 1 and then open up a new window and login as user 2 and I go back to user 1's window and refresh the page I now have user 2 profile_pic for user 1. The $_SESSION data **e.g: profile_pic** is being read from a central file called loggedinuser.php which does 2 things: **1** checks to see if the user has logged in and **2** if so echo the session in json format. This is where I believe the problem is because the data is coming back correctly but each time the user logs in it reinitializes the session data to the last user who logged in. I have tried to using $_COOKIE to store the data but I get the same results. I tried using session_regenerate_id but get the same results. Prior to building the application I was under the impression that PHP takes care of unique sessions for each user. So my question is how do I set up my SESSIONS so that it returns the correct data that corresponds to each user login? **Note I'm using JQuery to fetch the data from loggedinuser.php** All help is appreciated.

Comment: Try to open 2 `$_SESSION` sessions from 2 different users in different webbrowsers (firefox, chrome, ie) and be amazed

Comment: Thanks Daan now I think its just a matter of the browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A PHP session it's a browser session. If you open the same login page on the same browser it will use the same session.

If you try a different browser you'll get different sessions. You can also try a new browser window in private/incognito mode.

There's no error at all in what you're describing.

Comment: It looks like your correct when i open use a different browser it works fine but now the profile pic isn't showing up in firefox or safari I am debugging now will let you the final outcome